# UI-Router State Listener Directive

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `ul` list in Angular using UI-Router. It creates a list based on the `$scope` data and correctly marks the anchor `active` based on the state. However, I'm having trouble finding an elegant way to mark the `li` parent as active for styling purposes.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a ui-sref="{{item.sref}}" ui-sref-active="active">
            {{item.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JSON:

```
$scope.items = [
    {name:'Foo Stuff',sref:'foo'},
    {name:'Bar Things',sref:'bar'},
]
```

I was hoping there was some CSS cheat code that would allow me to style an element based on a child element's class. If possible, I'd like to find a solution without adding any additional framework(s). Right now I'm using Angular JS, UI-Bootstrap, and UI-Router. All feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I figured it out 0.69 seconds after posting the question. It's seems so simple that I question its correctness. I just moved `ui-sref-active="active` to the parent `li`.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref-active="active>
        <a ui-sref="{{item.sref}}">
            {{item.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```